# Does larger cache size always lead to improved performance?

Tags: caching, memory, cpu, processor

Since cache inside the processor increases the instruction execution speed. I'm wondering what if we increase the size of cache to many MBs like 1 GB. Is it possible? If it is will increasing the cache size always result in increased performance?

Comment: Cache size does matter. for intel its the size, more instructions on the die, that's why they
have 12 mb of L3 cache. for amd is for gaming, the cache empties out and refills as soon as the processor uses it. That's why intel thinks allot. and amd does not.
i preffer amd anyway.

Answer (score 7):

There is a tradeoff between cache size and hit rate on one side and read latency with power consumption on another. So the answer to your first question is: technically (probably) possible, but unlikely to make sense, since L3 cache in modern CPUs with size of just a few MBs has read latency of about dozens of cycles.

Performance depends more on memory access pattern than on cache size. More precisely, if the program is mainly sequential, cache size is not a big deal. If there are quite a lot of random access (ex. when associative containers are actively used), cache size really matters.

The above is true for single computational tasks. In multiprocess environment with several active processes bigger cache size is always better, because of decrease of interprocess contention.

Answer (score 6):

This is a simplification, but, one of the primary reasons the cache increases 'speed' is that it provides a fast memory very close to the processor - this is much faster to access than main memory. So, in theory, increasing the size of the cache should allow more information to be stored in this 'fast' memory, and thereby improve performance.. In the real world things are obviously much more complex than this, and there will of course be added complexity, and cost, associated with such a large cache, and with dealing with issues like cache coherency, caching algorithms etc.

Answer (score -1):

As cache stores data temporary. Cache is used to locate the file easily that has been frequently using. So if the size of cache increased upto 1gb or more it will not stay as cache, it becomes RAM. Data is stored in ram temporary. So if cache isn't used, when data is called by processor, ram will take time to fetch data to provide to the processor because of its wide size of 4gb or more. So we use cache as our temporary memory for the things we recently or frequently used. In this way, ram ram doesnt required to find and fetch data to give it to processor, because processor direct access data from cache, because of small size of cache, it doesnt take time to find data, and processor doesn't require to call ram to fetch data, all of this done fastly without ram. Lets take an example, we have a wide classroom (RAM) , our principal (processor) call class CR (Data)  for some purposes, then ones will go to the class room and will find the CR in the class of 1000 students and take him to the principal. It takes time. When we specify a space(cache) for CR in the class, because principal mostly call CR of the class, so it will become easy to find CR becuase most of the time CR is called by Principal.